# Undeclared identifier "UIColor" in my tweak in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cydia, tweak

I am trying to make a tweak in Xcode with IOSOpenDev, but i met an error which is `Use of undeclared identifier "UIColor"`!
I used the same code from my iPhone yet it works, why doesn't it work here? (I want to use IOSOpenDev since it looks much better then using theos)

This is the code

```
%hook SBScreenFlash

-(void)flashColor:(id)color {

NSDictionary *prefs=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.junyi00.screenshotcolor.plist"];

if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"enable"] boolValue]){
    color = [UIColor blueColor];
    %orig(color); }
else {
    %orig; }
}

%end
```

Please help me here

Comment: If this is for OSX, then you shouldn't be using `UIKit` classes, you're probably looking for `NSColor`

Comment: After changing to `color = [NSColor blueColor];` Now they are telling me `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSColor'; did u mean 'NSCoder'?`

Comment: I am not sure what exactly it is you are using to write or compile this code, I don't recognize the `%` syntax you use.  If the compiler can't find `NSColor` you probably aren't linking the `AppKit` framework or aren't including `AppKit/AppKit.h`

Comment: I'm using xocde since IOSOpenDev is somewhat a plugin for Xcode which allows me to create iPhone tweaks and others just from Xcode

Comment: If this is for iOS, then `UIColor` is the class you want, you just need to make sure `UIKit` framework is linked, and you are `#include`ing `UIKit/UIKit.h`

Comment: I tried including `AppKit/AppKit.h` but they give me `'AppKit.h' file not found` error :(

Answer (score 6):

You should check if you have

```
PROJECTNAME_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit Foundation
```

Also

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

In your tweak.xm (On the top) like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

%hook SBScreenFlash

-(void)flashColor:(id)color {

NSDictionary *prefs=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.junyi00.screenshotcolor.plist"];

if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"enable"] boolValue]){
    color = [UIColor blueColor];
    %orig(color); }
else {
    %orig; }
}

%end
```